# Firebase await db.collection does not enter catch statement, awaiting forever

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, try-catch

Im making a small blog with GatsbyJS and Firebase. My blog is static, like usual gatsby blogs, but Im fetching comment data on firebase.

This is my function to fetch comment data

```
  //@@@ Fetch Comment Data function
 //function to fetch comment data 

 const fetchData = async () => {

   try {
           console.log("entered try")
           const commentRef = await db.collection("comments").doc(postID).get();
           setComments(commentRef.data().comments);
       } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
      }
}
```

The thing is, Im trying to write the exception as to when a post does not have comments, that is to say the document postID does not exist, and my try catch is never entering the catch block, it seems as if its stuck forever. And I am here wondering if this is an error with my async await syntax, my function syntax in general or a Firestore specific rule I am breaking.

If the document exists, as if I allready created the document via the firebase panel, this code works fine, no issues whatsoever. So I wanted to put in the catch statement that if the document does not exist for this postID I could create it or at least setState to show that there are no comments for this postID

Thanks

Comment: Is `setComments` method called? Try to write `console.log('foo')` after `await` method.

Comment: `setCommments` is just a useState hook method such as this `const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);`

I just did the console("foo") after the await, and its actually showing

So I continued to log, and I logged the commentRef and its actually returning stuff from firebase, even though the doc does not exist, it returns an empty object. So that might be the problem. 

Maybe I should write an if statement inside the try block to check if commentRef.data() is an empty object I should create the doc itself. But Im not so sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From firebase docs:

The following example shows how to retrieve the contents of a single document using get():

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

```js
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

> Note: If there is no document at the location referenced by docRef, the resulting document will be empty and calling exists on it will return false.

so the `get()` method won't ever throw an exception and that's why your catch block isn't running.
In your case you would achieve what you're up to like this:

```js
const fetchData = async () => {

const commentRef = await db.collection("comments").doc(postID).get().then(post => {

    try {
        if (!post.exists) {
           throw "Post doesn't exist";
        }
        setComments(post.data().comments);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

});

}
```

Code not tested...

Comment: Thanks, guess I didnt read the docs correctly! Thats what I thought Ill have to throw an an error inside an if. 

Again thanks

Comment: Happy I could help!